# How can I add some insets to the text inside the UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to add insets to the text inside the UILabel without subclassing it. Or even with UILabel subclass but without changing too much the code.
How can I do it?

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var data:CustomData? {
        didSet {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            //bg.image = data.image
            bg.text = data.title
        }
    }

    fileprivate let bg: UILabel = {
        let iv = UILabel()

        iv.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        iv.textAlignment = .center
        iv.numberOfLines = 0
        iv.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40)
        iv.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        iv.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 12

        return iv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.addSubview(bg)
        bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "too much code"? If you want to know how to do something, ask how to do it; don't impose restrictions on the answer before you even know what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `constant` parameter

```
bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,constant:30).isActive = true
```

---

for 30 pts inset do

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,constant:30),
    bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor,constant:30),
    bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor,constant:-30),
    bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor,constant:-30)
])
```

You can also set `UIEdgeInsets`

Answer (score 0):

Your entire approach is wrong. If the goal is to show the label text centered in `bg`, then `bg` should not *be* a label; it should *contain* a label, centered.

This example uses no code at all; the outer view self-sizes to the label, and the label's constraints to the outer view provide the insets:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, so how can I do that ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "how". My answer _is_ the "how". Added screen shots.